# How does Pistache server work on file upload?

Tags: c++, http, file-upload, server, openapi

i have created an api for file upload in openapi 3.0 . My YAML file is like below

```
paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      description: Upload a single Audio File
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                upload:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful to Upload file
          
        '400':  
          description: Fail to Upload File
```

in the server side my file upload part is looking like this now

```
void DefaultApiImpl::upload_post(const Pistache::Rest::Request &request, Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter &response){
    
    
    response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, "File Upload Complete..................... \n");
}
```

i am also getting response when i am trying to upload any file using the api . Problem is i am not getting any resource for server side for storing the file in a specific folder or destination. What i am missing in server side ?

Comment: Where do you handle the request body?

Comment: didn't handle till now. i have no idea, how to handle it. new in openapi

Comment: How is this related to OpenAPI?

Comment: I have created the server using openapi-genrator . So pistache server end created some default code base that i already attached above. Need a guideline for further control over the uploaded file, like store in a pecific location / add info to DB

Comment: So it looks like it creates a basic template but doesn't add any logic to handle the request body. You have to add it.